# except script error - extra characters after close-quote while executing

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh, except

I have a written an except script to ssh to different servers and change .bash_profiles. In my code, i am facing issue with sed command and getting below error.

extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"send "sed -i '/TERM/a \COL_YELLOW="$(tput setaf 3)"' .bash_profile_backup\r"
        expect eof"

I tried with all the combination, but its not working. I know its a small indentation issue. If someone could please help with the code.

OS - RHEL6.2.

### Code

```
for server in $(cat temp.lst);
do
{
expect -c "
    spawn ssh -t -t "nmehta\@$server"
    expect "?assword:"
    send \"$password\r\"
    send \"\r\"
    expect "?nmehta@?"
    send \"sudo -u oracle -i\r\"
    sleep 5
    expect "?assword:"
    send \"$password\r\"
    sleep 5
    send \"cp .bash_profile .bash_profile_backup\r\"
    send \"sed -i.bck 's/vt100/xterm/g' .bash_profile_backup\r\"
    send \"sed -i '/TERM/a \COL_YELLOW=\"\$(tput setaf 3)\"' .bash_profile_backup\r\"
    send \"sed -i '/TERM/a \COL_END="$(tput sgr0 1)"' .bash_profile_backup\r\"
    expect eof"
}
done
```

Comment: This is truly terrible formatting. I tried to reformat, but...I just couldn't

Comment: Sorry for that. this is my first post so messed it up. I have re-formatted again. If you could please help .

Comment: Can you really mix quotes like that? I feel like using all double quotes will mess things up. For example you main `expect -c` statement will get cut off at the next `"` on the next line.

Comment: I am using it in a shell script. Actually the code is working very fine. Its only the sed command which gives errors as mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Trying different indentation I finally was able to execute the script as below.

```
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/bin
export PATH

password=test123
export password

export TEMP_1='\"\$(tput setaf 3)\"'
export TEMP_1

export TEMP_2='\"\$(tput sgr0 1)\"'
export TEMP_2

TEMP_3="PS1='\''\\\${HOSTNAME} \[\\\$ORACLE_SID\] \\\$PWD> '\''"
export TEMP_3

for server in $(cat temp.lst);
do
{
expect -c "
     spawn ssh -t -t "nmehta\@$server"
    expect "?assword:"
    send \"$password\r\"
    send \"\r\"
    expect "?nmehta@?"
    send \"sudo -u oracle -i\r\"
    sleep 5
    expect "?assword:"
    send \"$password\r\"
    sleep 5
    send \"cp .bash_profile .bash_profile_backup\r\"
    send \"sed -i.bck s/vt100/xterm/g .bash_profile_backup\r\"
    send \"sed -i '/TERM/a \COL_YELLOW=$TEMP_1' .bash_profile_backup\r\"
    send \"sed -i '/TERM/a \COL_END=$TEMP_2' .bash_profile_backup\r\"
    expect eof"
}
done
```